# Divison operator ambiguity

Tags: java, math

```
Iclass Solution
{
   public double cToF(int C)
   {
        //Your code here
        double fh;
        fh = (C*(double)(9/5))+32; //C=32 F=64
        
        return fh;
   }
}

IIclass Solution
{
    public double cToF(int C)
    {
        //Your code here
        double fh; 
        fh = (C*1.8)+32; //C=32 F=89
        
        return fh;
    }
}
```

Please take a look on the above code. This code mainly coverts temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit. In the code I, when I used (9/5) in formula, I got the answer as 64. But in code II, when I used 1.8(9/5=1.8), I got as 89(correct one). Could anyone explain the logic behind that?

Comment: You are doing integer division in `9 / 5`  It is not ambiguous ... just the wrong thing to do in this context.  In Java `9 / 5` gives `1`.

Comment: 9/5 equals 1, since that's int division, so the result is int. You can use 9.0/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when you divide `9/5`, it takes `9` as well as `5` as an integer and then, it evaluates the whole answer as `integer` only. Thus, `9/5` (which is actually 1.8) is then type casted from `1.8` to `1`. The portion after decimal is truncated. Thus, in your first code, it multiplies everything with `1` so it gives wrong output.

Now you'll ask, **I have type casted into `double` then why?**

Well, the answer is that first it evaluates `9/5` which is equal to `1` (according to int division by computer). Then it type castes `1` into `double` i.e. `1.0`. Thus, you can instead use `9.0/5.0`. This will also give you correct answer.